# PHP - Based on which page I'm on, change the active class

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have 3 pages. Based on which page I'm on, I'd like to change the class of active to reflect that.

The 3 pages are index, blog, and contact. Each of them have sub-pages as well, like Work has various PHP files for various projects. Blog has various blog posts. Contact is just a PHP contact form.

I'd like to, based on what the person is on, move the class="active" around. Right now it's hard-coded on each page.

My Code is:

```
<ul class="list-inline" id="menu">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="index.php">work</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="blog.php">blog</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="contact.php">contact</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this PHP:

```
<?php #add class .active to current page
   $directoryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $path = parse_url($directoryURL, PHP_URL_PATH);
   $components = explode('/', $path);
   $currentPage = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($components));

   if ($currentPage == "") {
       $currentPage = "index";
   }

   function href($url) {
      global $currentPage;
      $path = explode('/', $url);
      $page = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($path));
      echo 'href="' . $url . '"';

      if ($page == $currentPage) {
         echo 'active';
      }
   }
?>
```

Adjust your menus to be like:

```
<li><a <?php href('about.php');?>>About</a></li>
```

**This should work.
Good luck*

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-inline" id="menu">
<li<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == "index.php") { echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>>
    <a href="index.php">work</a>
</li>
<li<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == "blog.php") { echo " class=\"active\""; } ?>>
    <a href="blog.php">blog</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="contact.php">contact</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

etcetera

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, one of which is this one:

```
<?php
$page = ''; // @TODO: assign with the right value
$work_class = $page == 'work' ? 'active' : '';
$blog_class = $page == 'blog' ? 'active' : '';
$contact_class = $page == 'contact' ? 'active' : '';
?>

<ul class="list-inline" id="menu">
    <li class="<?=$work_class?>">
        <a href="index.php">work</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li class="<?=$blog_class?>">
        <a href="blog.php">blog</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li class="<?=$contact_class?>">
        <a href="contact.php">contact</a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="social" src="img/icon/icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To get a more precise answer it was useful if you provided more precise information on how the rest of your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

i would loop it..

```
<?php
$base = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/')-1); // Something like this to determine the current file such as 'blog.php'
$links = array();
$links['work'] = 'index.php';
$links['blog'] = 'blog.php';
// ..

foreach($links AS $name => $url)
{ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"
    <?php if($base == $url) ?> class="active"<?php } ?>
    ><?php echo $name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

you can add the active classes to wrapping li elements too ofc.